# How to read HD serial in Linux without root privileges?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am building a C/C++ program which needs to read the HD serial. I am aware that if I run these commands:

```
hdparm -i /dev/sda | grep -i serial

/sbin/udevadm info --query=property --name=sda | grep "ID_SERIAL"
```

I can get it, the first requires root permissions but the second doesn't.

However, my application cannot access external programs, and it cannot require root privileges, so is there a C/C++ linux library that has a function that returns the HD serial? Or is there any other way that does not require running a program?

Comment: Remember that the `hdparm` and `udevadm` programs are, like most of every other core Linux utilities, open source. So why not simply download the source to them and check what they do?

Comment: My guess is you will need to open `/bin/sda` and use IOCTL's to read the serial number.

Comment: Thanks, it is surely an option, although understandinf the code and replicating it can get very complicated, maybe there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Can it be done? I don't think so. You need root privileges...

Comment: What do you need this information for? If it's for copy protection, keep in mind that some computers (e.g, virtual machines) may not have a hard drive serial number at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By just listing `/dev/disk/by-id/` directory, you get IDs of all block devices on your system. The output is not exactly the same as with the commands, but it is close enough.

For this, you do not need root privileges.

---

On my PC :

```
$ /sbin/udevadm info --query=property --name=sda | grep "ID_SERIAL"
ID_SERIAL=WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EHJ93860
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=WD-WCC2EHJ93860
```

and

```
$ ll /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Nov 11 07:47 ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EHJ93860 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 11 07:47 ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EHJ93860-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 11 07:47 ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EHJ93860-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 11 07:47 ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-60U6AA0_WD-WCC2EHJ93860-part3 -> ../../sda3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ioctls to access hard drive information, just as hdparm does. The `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY` ioctl should be sufficient for your needs. It returns a structure which (IIRC) includes the serial number; googling around should help you find the structure definition.

Comment: Problem with this is that it requires root privileges, and I cannot require that from my program. Thanks anyway